# Pushing a SplitViewController from another SplitViewController

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad application with a SplitViewController in which the DetailView has a UIButton. What I want to know is, is it possible to show another SplitViewController on pressing that button? I couldn't see such a functionality implemented by anyone, after lots of Googling around.

Thank you.

Comment: where do you want the "new" split view controller to go? if you want to replace the one already on screen why not change this one to show what you want to show?

Comment: On the button click i want the existing splitview controller to be replaced by the new one..this is what we are trying for but failed to find so..!! Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response everyone. I got the solution for the same.

What I did was I created a `UIViewController` (for Detail page) and a `UITableViewController` (for Master Page). By implementing `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` & `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` in detail page , I linked up both of them(detail & master) by making the splitviewcontroller the root view controller of Detail Page.

Basic split view functions and popover functions are to be implemented. You will have to manually adjust the size of the MasterPopoverView.

Comment: This does not answer the fact that "can you have 2 splitViewControllers"

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by sending a notification to the parent of the spiltview. Like if you have a UINavigationController or any other viewcontroller that is holding the original SplitView you want to subscribe it to a notification and when the button is tapped you send a notification as a result of which the parent replaces (or modifies) the split view with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push a `UISplitViewController` [image]